# SQLiteOpenHelper multiple record update

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In my android application I am using Sqliteopenhelper to manipulate the sqlite database. I need to update a field  (f1) in a table with part of another field (f2) for all records which meet a particular criteria. Which in standard sql can be written as

```
update table1 set f1=substr(f2,1,length(f2)-3) where f1 like 'xxx%';
```

Not sure how to do it in sqliteopenhelper.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` method of Android's `SQLiteDatabase` class would require that you use `ContentValues`, which supports only literal values, not arbitrary SQL expressions.

Just use `execSQL`:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE table1 SET f1=substr(f2,1,length(f2)-3) WHERE f1 like ? || '%'",
           new Object[] { "xxx" });
```

Comment: It's string concatentation in SQL. You could just as well do this in Java with `"xxx" + "%"`.